# Can my Google history, Facebook activity, and Stackexchange Q&A be used for state permit/license background checks?

Tags: united-states

This is a follow-up for [Could there be consequences for Googling how to do something that is normally a crime?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/81814/could-there-be-consequences-for-googling-how-to-do-something-that-is-normally-a)

The state often conducts background checks for various reasons. For example, CA conducts background checks for certain permits and licenses, for example for a firearm purchase. Can the state use my social media activity as a part of that background check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any protection regarding social media accounts and background checks?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/80833/is-there-any-protection-regarding-social-media-accounts-and-background-checks)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, the question is very similar indeed. Unfortunately the answers are about the employers' use of social media account for background checks, not the states doing the same for issuing permits & licenses.

Comment: If it is public, it is legal

Comment: The linked question seems to ask about the sue of such posts by a private emloyer, not by a government agency. Rules for government are often soemewhat different, hence I think this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen Not broadly. If a private employer, in conducting a background check, checked your Facebook profile and found that you had a 1-year old child and therefore refused to hire you, that would be illegal in many jurisdictions that ban employment discrimination based on familial status.